# c# Error CS0120 - Having trouble with Object References

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to make a door open system using keys, but I can't do it because one error keeps coming up.
`error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property`
I would expect it to get the object from the script named DoorBehaviour, but no.

Here is my code:

```
..
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class SwitchBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private InputActionReference press;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        press.action.performed += PerformPress;
    }

    private void PerformPress(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
        DoorBehaviour.OpenDoor();
    }

    private void OnDisable() {
        press.action.performed -= PerformPress;
    }
}
```

Comment: `DoorBehaviour` seems to be a class name which has instance method `OpenDoor`. You can have multiple `DoorBehaviour` in your game, which one the switch should open?

Comment: Ok you dont show doorbehavior. But lets say you called something here. You cant write "SwitchBehavior.PerformPress" because how does it know which one you could have 2000 in your sceen. You are a class human. But if i say human speak how does it know which human i meant. I need to reference the human instance of you. And then say speak and it knows im speaking to you.

Comment: @GuruStron I do not have multiple DoorBehaviour

Comment: It doesn;t matter whether you have multiple or not. The point is that you can have multiple so you can't just tell the class itself to do something and it magically know which object of that type to do it to. It's up to you to tell it which object to use, which is exactly what the error message is telling you. You have presumably created a `DoorBehaviour` object somewhere and assigned it to a variable. You need to use that variable to refer to that object to call that method on that object.

Comment: Post your DoorBehaviour script. Its difficult to give an exact answer without that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you're trying to call an instance function like you would call a static function. So you will need to either make your DoorBehaviour.OpenDoor() a static function like this:

```
public class DoorBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
   ...
   public static OpenDoor() { ... }
   ...
}
```

or create a DoorBehavior variable and call it from that variable like this:

```
public DoorBehaviour doorBehaviour;
...
private void PerformPress(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
{
        doorBehaviour.OpenDoor();
}
```

And then set the doorBehaviour variable to the game object in your scene that contains the DoorBehaviour script using the inspector. Though without seeing the full error and your DoorBehaviour script, we can't say exactly what the issue is for certain. Hope this helps either way though.